# Using assignment operators in Dart

Tags: dart, operators, variable-assignment

```
void main()
{
  var a=10;
  var b=2;
  var toplam=a+=b;
  var fark=a-=b;
  var carpim=a*=b;
  var bolme=a/=b;
  print("$toplam");
  print("$fark");
  print("$carpim");
  print("$bolme");
}
```

This code gives the following error when splitting:
"A value of type 'double' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```dart
var a=10;
```

the type of `a` is inferred from the right-hand-side of the assignment.  The right-hand-side is an `int` literal, so `a` is inferred to be of type `int`.

Later when you try to do:

```dart
var bolme=a/=b;
```

the `a /= b` part fails because [`int.operator /`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/operator_divide.html) always returns a `double`, and therefore that result can't be assigned to `a` which can store only `int`s.

If you want `a` to be able to store `double`s, then you must declare it to be a `double` (or to be a `num`, the base class for `int` and `double`):

```dart
double a = 10;
```

or

```dart
var a = 10.0;
```

or

```dart
num a = 10;
```

Alternatively if your intent is to perform integer division, you should be using [`int.operator ~/`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html):

```dart
var a = 10;
var b = 2;
var bolme = a ~/= b;
```